# Adding another suffix to a path that already has a suffix with pathlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

I was converting some old Python code to use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) instead of `os.path` for most path-related operations, but I ended up with the following problem: I needed to add another extension to a path that already had an extension (not replace it). With `os.path`, since we are merely manipulating strings, the solution was to add the extension with string operations:

```
newpath = path + '.res'
```

It doesn't work with `pathlib.Path` because it doesn't allow concatenation of arbitrary characters. The closest I could find was the following:

```
newpath = path.with_suffix(path.suffix + '.res')
```

It looks like a workaround because it still uses string addition in the end. And it has a new pitfall because I forgot at first to handle the case where there are already several extensions and you want to add a new one, leading to the following code to get back the old behaviour:

```
newpath = path.with_suffix(''.join(path.suffixes) + '.res')
```

Now it doesn't feel terse nor clean since it uses more and more string operations to achieve the old behaviour instead of pure path operations. The fact that `Path.suffixes` exists means that the library's developers considered the case where a file can have multiple extensions, yet I couldn't find a way to simply add a new extension to a path. Is there a more idiomatic way that I have missed to achieve the same behaviour?

EDIT: actually `path.with_suffix(path.suffix + '.res')` is enough to handle the case where there are already several file extensions, even though it wasn't immeditely obvious to me.

Comment: Didn't see your edit until after posting my answer... that seems like a pretty good solution too

Comment: it seems there was no better answer than the one-liner you already had. pathlib seems to have some very annoying fatal flaws that make it more difficult to work with than plain strings -- case in point, if you wanted to add the suffix `_foo.res` with your method, you get `ValueError: Invalid suffix`, because it doesn't start with a dot!

Comment: Should probably select an answer...

Comment: @MadPhysicist I would if I considered that there was a single good answer, but as evidenced by the answer mentioning `pathlib3x` there isn't a clean solution in the standard library (and I don't want to add a new dependency for a whole library), and while several of the proposed alternative are valid, none feel satisfying. I'd rather let the mass pick their favourite answer.

Comment: @Morwenn. In the meantime, your question is lingering in the unanswered queue, while some unlucky person is lacking their 15 pts

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'm aware of that, unfortunately the unanswered queue and points aren't really something I care about anymore. I consider actually meaningful accept marks to bear a greater value for the overall community.

Comment: @spinup, I don't claim there are no flaws. But this particular behaviour seem quite correct imho: a suffix in term of pathnames are seperated by a `.`.
You should do it with _name_, i.e. `path.with_name(path.name + "_foo.res")`.

Comment: @doak  Looking at this years after my original comment, I think I was looking at the case of changing a pathname from `/a/b/c/file.ext` to `/a/b/c/file_foo.ext`. The `with_suffix` method would seem to fit the bill perfectly to strip off the extension and add a new ending to the name, but for some reason they chose to artificially limit the method and throw an error instead.

Answer (score 109):

I find the following slightly more satisfying than the answers that have already been given:

```
new_path = path.parent / (path.name + '.suffix')
```

Comment: Glorious. Had been struggling with this - I hadn't thought of the parentheses.

Comment: Ever so slightly more streamlined version: `new_path = path.parent / f"{path.name}.suffix"`

Answer (score 31):

It doesn't seem like Path's like being modified in-place (you can't change `.parts[-1]` directory or change `.suffixes`, etc.), but that doesn't mean you need to resort to anything too unsavory. The following works just fine, even if it's not quite as elegant as I'd like:

```
new_path = path.with_suffix(path.suffix + new_suffix)
```

where `path` is your original Path variable, and `new_suffix` is the string with your new suffix/extension (including the leading ".")

Comment: If you are going to write out both extensions, it would probably be more canonical to write as `new_path = path.with_suffix(new_suffix)`

Comment: your answer would substitute the suffix, not add it

Comment: @ImanolUr I assumed "new_suffix" would include everything desired. See the edited code for a more intuitive answer.

Comment: But... `path.parent / path.name` is exactly equivalent to the original `path` so how is that different from OP's `path.with_suffix(path.suffix + '.res')`?

Answer (score 14):

You can just convert your `Path` to string then add new extension and convert back to `Path`:

```
from pathlib import Path
first = Path("D:/user/file.xy")
print(first)
second = Path(str(first)+".res")
print(second)
```

Comment: You can also monkey patch it: `Path.__add__ = lambda self, rhs: Path(str(self) + rhs)`

Answer (score 14):

You might use pathlib3x - it offers a backport of the latest (at the date of writing this answer Python 3.11.a0) Python pathlib for Python 3.6 or newer, and a few additional functions like `append_suffix`

```
>>> python -m pip install pathlib3x

>>> import pathlib3x as pathlib

>>> pathlib.Path('some_path').append_suffix('.ext')
PosixPath('some_path.ext')
>>> pathlib.Path('some_path.ext.ext2').append_suffix('.ext3')
PosixPath('some_path.ext.ext2.ext3')
```

you can find it on [github](https://github.com/bitranox/pathlib3x) or [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/pathlib3x)

---

<sup>Disclaimer: I'm the author of the pathlib3x library.</sup>

Comment: Do you know how maintained that repo will be in the future?

Comment: Cool, now that's something I would like in the standard library :o

Comment: @Dash: it will be maintained as long as I live - then You can take over ;-) since I use it every day ...

Comment: @Morwenn that was one of the reasons I did it - on one hand it is clear that devs dont want to clutter the standard library, on the other hand I want to add useful functions, in a way that is compatible and in line with the style of the standard library. Just to make my own code more readable and less verbose.

Comment: That's really convenient, thanks!
However when passing such a path object to joblib I got a `ValueError: Second argument should be a filename or a file-like object, ../data/processed/blabla.pkl (type <class 'pathlib3x.pathlib3x.PosixPath'>) was given.`, which does't happen with the standard pathlib objects. 
Is it because joblib doesn't recognizes `pathlib3x.pathlib3x.PosixPath` as a PosixPath?
In the meantime I just need to add `.as_posix()`, but it would be great if we wouldn't have to.

Answer (score 9):

I think this would be better since you just want to extend the current path with an arbitrary string.

```
old_path = Path("/the/old/path.foo")  # "/the/old/path.foo"
new_path = Path(f"{old_path}.bar")    # "/the/old/path.foo.bar"
```

Comment: This is surprisingly the most readable code. Pathlib went too far with suffixes and forgot the most simple thing.

Comment: @march That can't be said enough. In all of the praise for pathlib, it seems like folks forgot the principle that simple things should be simple... especially things that used to be simple and are now hard, like appending a suffix.

Comment: I like it. Its simple and clear, and easy-readable

Answer (score 1):

if  you want to append the file name, but not change the extension, this works

```
matfile2 = pathlib.Path.joinpath(matfile.parent, matfile.stem+' insert'+matfile.suffix)
```

Answer (score -1):

The following code should do what you want it to in a very dynamic way.

```
from pathlib import Path
import time

p = Path('.')
p = p / '..' / 'Python' / 'Files' / 'Texts_to_read' / 'a_text_file'

new_p = str(p).split('\\')

new_suffix = '.txt'

new_p[-1] = new_p[-1] + new_suffix

p = Path('.')

for x in new_p:
    p = p / x

print(new_p)

print(p)
print(str(p))

time.sleep(5)
```

The fact that normal string operations can be used in this case is a good thing, as it adds a great deal of control over the file path desired without requiring a large assortment of new functions.