# Adding a suffix to a full path's name, before the extension

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, pathlib

I am moving some of my code from [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) to [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) and found that in general it is much better.

On a specific task I found that actually [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) might be more comfortable to use. I want to create a new path from a given one, by adding a suffix to its name and keeping the same root and extension. For example, from:

```
/a/b/c/file.txt
```

I want to get:

```
/a/b/c/file_test.txt
```

Using [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html), this can be done easily with [`splitext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext):

```py
>>> import os
>>> path = "/a/b/c/file.txt"
>>> base, ext = os.path.splitext(path)
>>> base + "_test" + ext
'/a/b/c/file_test.txt'
```

But, going over the [`pathlib`'s docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), I found [`with_name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.with_name) and [`with_suffix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.with_suffix) and got something like:

```py
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> path = Path("/a/b/c/file.txt")
>>> path.with_suffix('').with_name(path.stem + "_test").with_suffix(path.suffix)
PosixPath('/a/b/c/file_test.txt')
```

Which I believe is far worse than the [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) version.

Is there a better, cleaner way of achieving this with [**`pathlib`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mixing some of your approaches, you can also do:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path("/a/b/c/file.txt")
path.with_name(path.stem + '_test' + path.suffix)
# PosixPath('/a/b/c/file_test.txt')
```

Answer (score 6):

After finding [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60281933/6045800) about adding another **extension** to a path, I found that a cleaner way of doing this can be:

```py
>>> path = Path("/a/b/c/file.txt")
>>> path.parent / (path.stem + "_test" + path.suffix)
PosixPath('/a/b/c/file_test.txt')
```