# pathlib full list of methods

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, pathlib

What is the iPython code/command to list the methods in this case from the pathlib module?

**Rationale** I use pathlib for example to switch between genetic data file formats. In this example from `myfile.txt` to `myfile.md` (markdown),

```
fileIn = Path.home() / inFile
fileOut = fileIn.with_suffix('.md')
```

This solution is from Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49380572/adding-another-suffix-to-a-path-that-already-has-a-suffix-with-pathlib) because the pathlib [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is limited for this module. There must be inline help?

Comment: Does [How to list all functions in a Python module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139180/how-to-list-all-functions-in-a-python-module) help you here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who can't be bothered to run `inspect.getmembers(Path)`, here's the list of available functions for `Path` (as of pathlib 1.0.1, Python 3.8.3):

```
absolute
anchor
as_posix
as_uri
chmod
cwd
drive
exists
expanduser
glob
group
home
is_absolute
is_block_device
is_char_device
is_dir
is_fifo
is_file
is_mount
is_reserved
is_socket
is_symlink
iterdir
joinpath
lchmod
link_to
lstat
match
mkdir
name
open
owner
parent
parents
parts
read_bytes
read_text
relative_to
rename
replace
resolve
rglob
rmdir
root
samefile
stat
stem
suffix
suffixes
symlink_to
touch
unlink
with_name
with_suffix
write_bytes
write_text
```

Answer (score 1):

With thanks to @hemmelig

```
import inspect 
from pathlib import Path

inspect.getmembers(Path)
```

and for a more detailed description,

```
help()
>pathlib
```

Easy when you know how.